# Laravel not storing multiple images through Storage::disk

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

overflowers!
Today I encountered an issue while storing generated QR code images. At first it was working, but for some reason it stopped working and I can't figure where's the problem. Here's the code:

```
public function generate(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request->all());

        $data = $request->validate([
            'table_count' => 'required'
        ]);
        Auth::check();
        $user = Auth::user();

        $restaurant = $user->restaurants->where('selected', 1)->first();

        $qrCodes = ModelsQrcode::where('restaurant_id', $restaurant->id)->get();

        foreach ($qrCodes as $qr) {
            File::delete($qr->path);
        }


        for ($i=1; $i <= $data['table_count']; $i++) { 
            $image = QrCode::format('png')
                 ->size(200)
                 ->generate('http://192.168.8.103:8000/detectagent?table='.$i);
            $output_file = 'qr_images/img-' . time() . '.png';
            Storage::disk('public')->put($output_file, $image);

            $compiledPath = '/storage/'.$output_file;

            $newQR = ModelsQrcode::create([
                'path' => $compiledPath,
                'table' => $i
            ]);

            $newQR->restaurant()->associate($restaurant)->save();

        }

        return redirect('/QRgenerator');
    }
```

So basically I'm generating specified number of QR codes and each have different table assigned, which are added in url parameters. At first it was creating different QR's and was working just fine, I don't recall changing anything here, but for unknown reasons it just stopped working. Now if I try generating for example 3 QR codes, 3 database rows are created and assigned the same image, therefore if i check the storage folder there's only 1 image created. What could be the problem?
I'm using `simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode` library.

Comment: Maybe `time()`is the same and it overwrites files? Try to see if Str::random() can help

Comment: @StewieSWS It seems that was the case, `Str::random()` solved my problem, thank you!